# R openair installation fails after upgrade to MRAN 3.4.1

Tags: r, installation, openair

I've been using the openair package on my mac with Rstudio and MRAN v 3.4 for some time with no problem. I recently upgraded to MRA v 3.4.1 and am now getting the following messages, that ultimately end in an error. Suggestions on how to fix appreciated.

```
> install_github('davidcarslaw/openair')
Downloading GitHub repo davidcarslaw/openair@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/davidcarslaw/openair/zipball/master
Installing openair
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/bv/881_rsvd2kv83c13yywwc_xh0000gn/T/Rtmpz6778s/devtoolscf5234a1e7d/davidcarslaw-openair-b782399'  \
  --library='/Users/gcn/Library/R/3.4/library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘openair’ ...
** libs
clang-omp++ -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Users/gcn/Library/R/3.4/library/Rcpp/include" -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -std=c++11 -c cluster.cpp -o cluster.o
clang-omp -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Users/gcn/Library/R/3.4/library/Rcpp/include" -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native  -std=gnu99 -c init.c -o init.o
init.c:26:2: warning: no newline at end of file [-Wnewline-eof]
}
 ^
1 warning generated.
clang-omp++ -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Users/gcn/Library/R/3.4/library/Rcpp/include" -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -std=c++11 -c rolling.cpp -o rolling.o
clang-omp++ -fopenmp -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/clang4/lib -o openair.so cluster.o init.o rolling.o -framework Accelerate -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
installing to /Users/gcn/Library/R/3.4/library/openair/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.1-MRO/Resources/library/Matrix/libs/Matrix.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.1-MRO/Resources/library/Matrix/libs/Matrix.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.1-MRO/Resources/library/Matrix/libs/Matrix.so
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘openair’
* removing ‘/Users/gcn/Library/R/3.4/library/openair’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away after I uninstalled all R versions and then installed MRAN version 3.4.2 when it came out. According to MRAN software support "You're right, it is a bug in MRO 3.4.1. Because MRO uses the Accelerate libraries for BLAS and LAPACK operations, it does not create the libRblas and libRlapack dylibs; binary packages that use those libraries are currently incompatible with MRO, but the default package type was set in MRO 3.4.1 to "macbinary-el-capitan". This has been changed in the upcoming MRO 3.4.2 back to the original "source". "